# Execute java command as build configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, build, jar

I use MultiRun plugin to build the backend services and the UI in the same Run. I need to run a java command before all this and i want to include it in the multirun configuration i'm using. The command is like:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8001
```

Which option in the configurations list should i use to set this?.

Thanks.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/265-batch-scripts-support or External Tool should help.

Comment: That worked! thanks